# How to update a child component's props in a test case?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function that should get invoked when a prop (newItems) changes:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { title } = this.state;
    const { newItems } = this.props;
    const { newItems: prevNewItems } = prevProps;

    if (prevNewItems !== newItems) {
      this.updateTitle(title, newItems); // testing if this method gets called
    }
  }
```

The problem on the test below is that componentDidUpdate lifecycle hook doesn't register a new prop after I call setProps, thus the spy receives "0 number of calls"

```
it('calls updateTitle when newItems changes', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MyComponent {...props} newItems={0}/>
    </Provider>,
  );

  const MyComponentWrapper = wrapper.find('MyComponent');
  const spy = jest.spyOn(MyComponentWrapper.instance(), 'updateTitle');

  wrapper.setProps({
    children: <MyComponent {...props} newItems={1} /> 
  });
  wrapper.update();

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Received number of calls: 0 (should be 1) 
});
```

How can I update props on a child component (MyComponent) that is wrapped in a Provider?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. It works fine for me. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can update the props of the child component (MyComponent) by passing new props to the wrapper.setProps() method. Instead of passing children property, pass the updated newItems property:

```
wrapper.setProps({
  newItems: 1
});
```

You can then call `wrapper.update()` to re-render the component with the updated props.

After this, the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method should be triggered, and the updateTitle method should be called with the updated newItems prop.